# UITapGestureRecognizer on subview of MKAnnotationView not working. SWIFT

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mapkit, mkannotationview

I have a `MKAnnotationView` with an image subview.

I try to add an `UITapGestureRecognizer` to it but there is no response

```
var tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "annotationClicked:")                    
                imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
                imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
                pinView.addSubview(imageView)
                pinView.bringSubviewToFront(imageView)
```

I'm afraid I have no idea why

Answer (score 1):

To react on the tap of an annotation view (`leftCalloutAccessoryView` or `rightCalloutAccessoryView`) you have to create the view as a descendant of `UIControl`. Then you can implement the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` method of the `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol. No need to use a gesture recognizer.

Here is a code snipped which adds a button as a callout accessory to a pinAnnotation:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
    if annotation is PinAnnotation {
        let pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "myPin")

        pinAnnotationView.pinColor = .Purple
        pinAnnotationView.draggable = true
        pinAnnotationView.canShowCallout = true
        pinAnnotationView.animatesDrop = true

        // button as callout accessory
        let deleteButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
        deleteButton.frame.size.width = 44
        deleteButton.frame.size.height = 44
        deleteButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        deleteButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "trash"), forState: .Normal)

        pinAnnotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = deleteButton

        return pinAnnotationView
    }

    return nil
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView!, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl!) {
    if let annotation = view.annotation as? PinAnnotation {
        self.mapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)
    }
}
```